# How to use mnlogit with different choice set for different alternatives

Tags: r, mlogit

I have a dataset similar to below, where I have a different choice set for different alternatives. For example for `chid=1` we have `alt1` to `alt4`, but for `chid=2` we have `alt5` to `alt9`.

```
mode    income  alt     price   catch chid  weight
FALSE   7083    alt1    157.93  0.0678  1   10
FALSE   7083    alt2    157.93  0.2601  1   10
TRUE    7083    alt3    182.93  0.5391  1   10
FALSE   7083    alt4    157.93  0.0503  1   10
FALSE   1250    alt5    15.11   0.1049  2   20
FALSE   1250    alt6    10.53   0.1574  2   20
TRUE    1250    alt7    34.53   0.4671  2   20
FALSE   1250    alt8    15.11   0.0451  2   20
FALSE   3750    alt9    161.87  0.5333  2   20
TRUE    3750    alt10   24.33   0.2413  3   5
FALSE   3750    alt11   59.33   1.0266  3   5
FALSE   3750    alt12   161.87  0.4522  3   5
TRUE    7083    alt1    157.93  0.0678  4   2
FALSE   7083    alt2    157.93  0.2601  4   2
FALSE   7083    alt3    182.93  0.5391  4   2
FALSE   7083    alt4    157.93  0.0503  4   2
FALSE   1250    alt5    15.11   0.1049  5   40
TRUE    1250    alt6    10.53   0.1574  5   40
FALSE   1250    alt7    34.53   0.4671  5   40
FALSE   1250    alt8    15.11   0.0451  5   40
FALSE   3750    alt9    161.87  0.5333  5   40
FALSE   3750    alt10   24.33   0.2413  6   30
TRUE    3750    alt11   59.33   1.0266  6   30
FALSE   3750    alt12   161.87  0.4522  6   30
FALSE   7083    alt1    157.93  0.0678  7   25
TRUE    7083    alt2    157.93  0.2601  7   25
FALSE   7083    alt3    182.93  0.5391  7   25
FALSE   7083    alt4    157.93  0.0503  7   25
TRUE    1250    alt5    15.11   0.1049  8   20
FALSE   1250    alt6    10.53   0.1574  8   20
FALSE   1250    alt7    34.53   0.4671  8   20
FALSE   1250    alt8    15.11   0.0451  8   20
FALSE   3750    alt9    161.87  0.5333  8   20
FALSE   3750    alt10   24.33   0.2413  9   15
FALSE   3750    alt11   59.33   1.0266  9   15
TRUE    3750    alt12   161.87  0.4522  9   15
FALSE   7083    alt1    157.93  0.0678  10  8
FALSE   7083    alt2    157.93  0.2601  10  8
FALSE   7083    alt3    182.93  0.5391  10  8
TRUE    7083    alt4    157.93  0.0503  10  8
FALSE   1250    alt5    15.11   0.1049  11  6
FALSE   1250    alt6    10.53   0.1574  11  6
FALSE   1250    alt7    34.53   0.4671  11  6
TRUE    1250    alt8    15.11   0.0451  11  6
FALSE   3750    alt9    161.87  0.5333  11  6
FALSE   3750    alt10   24.33   0.2413  12  12
FALSE   3750    alt11   59.33   1.0266  12  12
TRUE    3750    alt12   161.87  0.4522  12  12
FALSE   1250    alt5    15.11   0.1049  13  15
FALSE   1250    alt6    10.53   0.1574  13  15
FALSE   1250    alt7    34.53   0.4671  13  15
FALSE   1250    alt8    15.11   0.0451  13  15
TRUE    3750    alt9    161.87  0.5333  13  15
```

I can use MNL for the case when every individual alternative.

```
dat1 <- fread('test_mnlogit.csv')
dat2 <- mlogit.data(data = dat1,choice = "mode", shape = "long", varying = 3:4, alt.var = "alt",chid.var = "chid")
fm <- formula(mode~-1+price+catch)
fit <- mnlogit(fm, dat2)
```

But when I use similar code for the following data type I get following error.

```
Error in mnlogit(fm, dat2) : 
  Mismatch between number of rows in data and number of choices.
```

You can download the test data here.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, `mlogit` doesn't handle varying choice sets. If the universal choice set contains 12 alternatives, then all cases have to have the same 12 choices.